# Add a JS app in Acquia root domain folder

Tags: 8, acquia-cloud

I have a decoupled app, both backend and frontend parts, and I want to add them to Acquia cloud. Right now the js app is placed in a subfolder in drupal's docroot folder.

What I need is to have the JS app in the domain's root folder and have Drupal instance in a subdomain or subfolder. Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

is your frontend an Angular / React / Vue app?

Anyway I don't know Acquia cloud but I can confirm that your setup works on an Apache server. I have my Angular app in the root folder along with the vendor and and web folders, and then I have in the web folder the core, libraries, modules eccc.. folders.